# How to use moq object in unit testing?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, moq

I am doing unit testing of one of my `Service layer class(ProductService)`.That layer serves DI facility to one of `controller class(ProductController)`.And for ProductController unit testing, there is already a unit test class ProductControllerTest.

But for unit test ProductController's **service layer(ProductService)**,i have created one new unit **test class(ProductServiceTest)**.

**But i don't know whether i should create a new unit test class to do Service Layer unit testing or not.**

**Also i want to know the concept of `DI(Dependency Injection) and Mocking(MOQ object)` in unit testing.Means where to use MOQ in unit testing and when it's necessary to use ?**

I have written unit test code for one of the action method of ProductService .And i want to know whether it's correct or not ?

Below is the piece of code of Action Method :-

```
public class ProductService : IProductService
{
    private readonly IProductDal<Product> _productDal;
    private readonly IUserDal<Users> _userDal;

    public ProductService(IProductDal<Product> ProductDAL)
    {
        _productDal = ProductDAL;
    }


    public List<ProductDto> GetProducts(string SearchInName, string SearchInDescription)
    {
          List<ProductDto> productList = new List<ProductDto>();
          foreach (Product product in _productDal.GetProducts(SearchInName, SearchInDescription))
          {
               productList.Add(Adapter.AdaptOmToDto(product));
          }
          return productList;
    }
}
```

Below is the piece of code of Unit Testing(ProductServiceTest) class :-

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetProductsTest()
    {
        var productList = new List<ProductDto>();

        // Arrrange            
        var Name = "CreateSave";
        var Description = "CreateSave";

        // Act
        List<ProductDto> output = _productService.GetProducts(Name, Description);

        // Assert       
        Assert.IsNotNull(output);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(output, typeof(List<ProductDto>));
    }
```

Can any one suggest me the best way to unit test such kind of methods ?

Comment: hi go to this link [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650441.aspx) I hope it will help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Also i want to know the concept of DI(Dependency Injection) and Mocking(MOQ object) in unit testing

Dependency Injection is the way we make our application adhere to [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod), which states that high-level modules should not depend on low-level modules - both should depend on abstractions. Depending on abstractions gives you low-coupling of units in system and ability to give any implementation of abstract dependency to dependent class. And here comes part related to unit-testing - you can give mocked implementation of dependency, which will allow you to verify behavior (see [Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) article) of unit under test.

You are already did a good job by making your `ProductService` depend on abstractions, and you used DI to inject abstraction implementation to service. What you need to test behavior of service is injecting mocked implementation of abstraction, and setting up expected interaction between `ProductService` and mock:

```
ProductService _productService;
Mock<IProductDal<Product>> _productDalMock;

[TestInitialize]
public void Setup()
{
    // create mock of dependency and pass mocked object to service
    _productDalMock = new Mock<IProductDal<Product>>();
    _productService = new ProductService(productDalMock.Object);
}

[TestMethod]
public void ShouldNotReturnDtosWhenProductsNotFound()
{
    // Arrrange 
    var name = "CreateSave";
    var description = "CreateSave";
    // setup mocked dal to return empty list of products
    // when name and description passed to GetProducts method
    _productDalMock.Setup(d => d.GetProducts(name, description))
                   .Returns(new List<Product>());

    // Act
    List<ProductDto> actual = _productService.GetProducts(name, description);

    // Assert
    Assert.False(actual.Any());
    // verify all setups of mocked dal were called by service
    _productDalMock.VerifyAll();
}
```

As you can see in test above, you can check whether product service called its dependency with correct parameters, and you can setup what data should dependency return to service. For next test you can setup mock to return list of predefined products. Then you will verify if appropriate dtos were returned by service.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Sergey.But i want to know when we pass moq object in service class constructor,will we able to fetch records from DAL class ?

As you know we have pass moq object to constructor and in this case i did not get any record in our "actual" object.I debugged the code and got that once control goes to DAL class while calling the GetProducts method the DAL object is just returning back not fetching records.

Comment: @Pawan you get in your 'actual' object exactly same records which you set up to return. If you set up mock to return empty list, it will return empty list to service. If you will provide some other list `.Returns(new List<Product> { new Product(), new Product() })` then these two products will be returned to service

Comment: Sergey thanks for your answer.I got the point,means when we use moq object than its just bypass the real object and returns the object that we created.

But i want to know what we need to do if there is a need to test real object ? And do should we test real object ?

Comment: @Pawan actually you do test real object - `ProductService` is real and this is your SUT (System Under Test). When you do *unit-testing* then your SUT should be real and all its dependencies mocked/stubbed. If there is more than one real object, then you are doing *integration* testing. If there is less then one real object in test, then test is useless :)

Comment: That's very helpful for me.Thanks for your answer @Sergey.
I have some more doubts about unit testing :-
>> What should be SUT in unit testing ? Means which area of code is SUT and which is dependency ?

Comment: @Pawan SUT is a class (unit) which behavior you want to verify. Dependencies are other classes (units) which are used by your SUT

Comment: ,i am doing Assertion by doing comparision of dto's and model object.Like this :-

 Assert.AreEqual(_oCustomer.FKCustomerId, actual.FKCustomerId);
 Assert.AreEqual(_oCustomer.Name,actual.Name);
 Assert.AreEqual(_oCustomer.Description,actual.Description);

But i want,instead of doing Assertion for every property in each test method can we have any default/automatic functionality for it ?

Can you guide me on that ?

Comment: @Pawan sure - you can override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` of customer, and then just compare customers like `Assert.AreEqual(_oCustomer, actual)`

Comment: thanks it helps me a lot.Also can you suggest me the best way to unit test a method that is returning void.